# What is the postgres_fdw CLOSE transaction and why does it block the table?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I just went to run a migration on my production database. The migration was a simple `ALTER TABLE .. add a column` on a small table. I had tested it locally, it ran in under a second. But when I deployed to production and the migration tried to run there it was blocked. When I queried `pg_stat_activity` I could see it was blocked by this query:

```
592635 | idle in transaction | postgres_fdw | 00:51:42.589821 | CLOSE c9
```

Can anyone tell me what this is? I have this database mounted to another database through postgres foreign data wrapper, so it's clearly related to this. But what is this query specifically, CLOSE, something? Why is it blocking if it's "idle"?

When this happened I tried to pg:kill the query and it wouldn't be killed. I instead killed the ALTER TABLE query.

Now (the next day) I check my pg:ps and this postgres_fdw is no longer present. But I want to learn from this incident so I can avoid having downtime in the future.

Comment: Somebody created a foreign table linking to your database and table. idle in transaction means that a transaction has been started, but not (yet) committed.

Comment: Which columns of pg_stat_activity are you showing there?

Comment: Something created a transaction and didn't commit it.  One of the statements in that transaction took a lock which is blocking you.  CLOSE didn't take the lock, it is merely the last statement which was executed in that transaction before it went idle.

Comment: As to what `"CLOSE` is see [CLOSE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-close.html). Seems postgres_fdw is using cursors behind the scene.

Comment: Can an “idle in transaction” be currently running? If so, then I guess something in the foreign database was running against it. But if it’s not running, then I’m still confused. There is regular query activity from the foreign database and some of those queries are long running, but nothing that would halt and leave a transaction unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

`CLOSE` closes a cursor. Since the state is "idle in transaction", the application forgot to close a transaction that used the table. You need to fix the application so that it closes its transactions.